# How do I update my Component (metadata) fields while copy/pasting a Component, using EventSystem?

Tags: event-system, 2011-sp1

I am trying to use the Eventsystem to update some (Metadata) Fields when a Component is copied (using copy+paste).

I do NOT get any content (or metadata) saved this way. However, I do get my new Title saved....
Any idea how I can get my Content/Metadata saved?

We do use Tridion 2011 SP1 (no HR!), could it be we need a hotfix here?

```
subscriptions.Add(EventSystem.Subscribe<Component, CopyEventArgs>(ComponentCopy, EventPhases.Processed)); 

        private void ComponentCopy(Component component, CopyEventArgs args, EventPhases phase)
    {
        Component newComp = (Component) args.CopiedObject;
        ItemFields content = new ItemFields(newComp.Content, newComp.Schema);
        XhtmlField body = (XhtmlField) content["body"];
        body.Value = "Er waren eens een heleboel kamelen " + DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString();
        newComp.Content = content.ToXml();

        ItemFields fields = new ItemFields(newComp.Metadata, newComp.Schema);
        EmbeddedSchemaField embeddedField = (EmbeddedSchemaField)fields["portal"];
        if (embeddedField != null)
        {
            ItemFields embeddedFields = embeddedField.Value;
            if (embeddedFields != null)
            {
                TextField bla = (TextField)embeddedFields["bla"];
                bla.Value = DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString();
                newComp.Metadata = embeddedFields.ToXml();
            }
        }


        // now SAVE the Component, as changes are NOT saved in this phase
        try
        {
            if (!newComp.IsCheckedOut)
            {
                newComp.CheckOut();
            }
            newComp.Title = "TEST-" + DateTime.Now;
            newComp.Save(true);
            if (newComp.IsCheckedOut) newComp.CheckIn();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            warn(string.Format("Could not save modified Component after Copy/Paste: {0}", ex.Message));
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So you set the title after making sure your Component is checked out, but you tried to sync back the changes of the content before ensuring it is checked out:

```cs
...
// sync content back to Component
newComp.Content = content.ToXml();
...
// sync metadata back to Component
newComp.Metadata = embeddedFields.ToXml();
...
if (!newComp.IsCheckedOut)
{
    newComp.CheckOut();
}
newComp.Title = "TEST-" + DateTime.Now;
newComp.Save(true);
```

Now if you would first check if your Component needs to be checked out before syncing back its content, then I think you will get a better result on your save. Because I expect that when you call `newComp.CheckOut();` all your previous actions on `newComp` will be reset.

So change it into something like this:

```cs
...
if (!newComp.IsCheckedOut)
{
    newComp.CheckOut();
}
newComp.Title = "TEST-" + DateTime.Now;
newComp.Content = content.ToXml();
newComp.Metadata = embeddedFields.ToXml();
newComp.Save(true);
```

*Note that the line `if (newComp.IsCheckedOut) newComp.CheckIn();` after calling `newComp.Save(true);` might undo a "permanent" lock that was set on the Component. Although that might be intentional of course.*

Comment: That's it, of course .... Long day...

Answer (score 7):

Bart already pointed out the proper order to do this check-out/modify/check-in cycle after the copy operation is performed.
Do note that this approach leads to a version 2 on the copy: version 1 is the unmodified copy and your post-processing creates a version 2.
This may be exactly what you want, but note that it is also possible to modify the copy without creating an additional version: you can also subscribe to the Initiated phase and modify the state of the subject (without check-out, save, or check-in).

Comment: It seems not possible to edit the Component while copying it. Copy/Paste will not trigger the save & checkin events, so it must be dealt with in (the initialized phase of the) copy-event. In this phase the copiedObject is still null. In order to modify the copied component, I must checkout & save the component in the processed phase of the copy event

Comment: What I meant is that you can change the in-memory state of the event subject (the `component` parameter in your example code) in the Initiated phase; you should not check-out/save/check-in that parameter (because it represents the source of the copy operation), but its state will be used as source of the copy operation (so will be reflected in version 1 of the copied object).  Unfortunately, I have to add that this trick only works for the `Title` property.